# My code for drawing will not receive values quickly enough to draw a steady line

Tags: python, tkinter

I receive this error from my code: `motion()` takes exactly 1 argument (0 given). How can I rework it or what do I need to change in order to get my code to draw a steady line or retrieve x and y values of the mouse quicker.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import*

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("PY Paint")
master = root
red_intvar = Tkinter.IntVar()
red_intvar.set(127)
blue_intvar = Tkinter.IntVar()
blue_intvar.set(127)
green_intvar = Tkinter.IntVar()
green_intvar.set(127)
r = 5
radius_intvar = Tkinter.IntVar()
radius_intvar.set(5)
mouse_released = True
mouse2_released = True
lines= IntVar()
'''initialize variables for the radius, radius slider, red, green, and blue color value, as well as the canvas'''

def new_radius(radius_intvar):
    global r
    r = radius_slider.get()
    r.append
'''creates a function for changing the radius of the circle when the slider is changed'''

canvas = Canvas(master, width= 1400, height = 800, relief=RAISED, bg='white')
canvas.grid()
Checkbutton(master, text='lines', variable=lines).grid(row=0, stick=W)
'''creates a canvas on which to draw'''

red_slider = Tkinter.Scale(master, from_=0, to=255, variable=red_intvar, 
                orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL, label = 'Red')
red_slider.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=Tkinter.E)
blue_slider = Tkinter.Scale(master, from_=0, to=255, variable=blue_intvar, 
                orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL, label = 'Blue')
blue_slider.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=Tkinter.E)
green_slider = Tkinter.Scale(master, from_=0, to=255, variable=green_intvar, 
                orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL, label = 'Green')
green_slider.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=Tkinter.E)
radius_slider = Tkinter.Scale(master, from_=1, to=20, variable=radius_intvar, 
                orient=Tkinter.VERTICAL, label = 'Pen Size', command= new_radius)
radius_slider.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky=Tkinter.E)
'''initializes and lays out the sliders for the color values and radius calue of the circle'''

def clear():
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 1400, 800, fill='white', outline='white')

clear_button = Button(master, text="clear",width=20, command=clear)
clear_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
'''defines and locates a button which is used to clear the canvas'''

def motion(event):
    global x
    global y
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print (x, y)
    canvas.after(1,motion)
root.bind('<Motion>', motion)
'''catures and sends back any change in the x and y values of the mouse on the canvas'''

print root.winfo_pointerxy()
def hexstring(slider_intvar):
    slider_int = slider_intvar.get()
    slider_hex = hex(slider_int)
    slider_hex_digits = slider_hex[2:]
    if len(slider_hex_digits)==1:
        slider_hex_digits = '0' + slider_hex_digits
    return slider_hex_digits
'''converts the slider values into hexidecimal digits'''

def pressed(element):
    global mouse_released
    mouse_released= False
    draw()

def released(element):
    global mouse_released
    mouse_released = True

def draw():
    global mouse_released
    global x
    global y
    if (x <= 1400):
        if (y <= 800):
            if (mouse_released == False):
                    canvas.create_rectangle(x-(.5*r), y-(.5*r), x+(.5*r), y+(.5*r), fill='#' + hexstring(red_intvar) + hexstring(green_intvar) + hexstring(blue_intvar),\
                    outline='#' + hexstring(red_intvar) + hexstring(green_intvar) + hexstring(blue_intvar))
                    canvas.after(1, draw)
'''draws a square of set area at the current position of the mouse, and loops based on if left click  is held'''

def m2_pressed(element):
    global mouse2_released
    mouse2_released= False
    erase()

def m2_released(element):
    global mouse2_released
    mouse2_released= True
    erase()

def erase():
    global mouse2_released
    if (x <= 1400):
        if (y <= 800):
            if (mouse2_released == False):
                canvas.create_rectangle(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, fill='white', outline='white')
                canvas.after(1, erase)
'''erases a square of set area at the current position of the mouse, and loops based on if right click is held'''

canvas.bind('<Button-1>', pressed)
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', released)
canvas.bind('<Button-3>', m2_pressed)
canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-3>', m2_released)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You get this error because at the end of `motion`, the line `.after(1, motion)` tells Tk to call the function `motion` again but with zero arguments.  You shouldn't be doing this anyway, since the <Motion> event already calls this function every time the mouse moves.  If the mouse isn't moving, there is no point in updating its coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please try to provide a [mcve] exactly specific to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The exception happens with this line in the `motion` function:

```
canvas.after(1,motion)
```

That `after` function gives no arguments to the callback. Which means it is calling your `motion` function without the `event` argument.

If I am not mistaken it seems your application also works when you delete that line, but I might be wrong.